# This function is not returning expected code

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return, conditional-statements

```
/* Task 3 */
```

//Dog feeder - Depending on their weight and age, we need to know how many pounds of food to feed our dog each day!
/*
Use the hungryDog function and feeding requirements below to do the following:

1. Invoke the hungryDog function below and pass it a weight value in pounds
2. Also, pass to hungryDog an age value in years (note: if the dog is a puppy, the age will be a decimal. For example: three months = 3/12 or .25)
3. Do the proper calculations and return the number of pounds of raw food to feed the dog/puppy in a day

REMEMBER: This program should handle correctly adult AND puppy ages and weights

Feeding Requirements:

Adult Dogs 1 year and older
up to 5 lbs - 5% of their body weight
6 - 10 lbs - 4% of their body weight
11 - 15 lbs - 3% of their body weight
> 15lbs - 2% of their body weight

Puppies less than 1 year
2 - 4 months 10% of their body weight
4 - 7 months 5% of their body weight
7 - 12 months 4% of their body weight

NOTE: If done correctly, a weight of 15 lbs and age of 1 year would return 0.44999999999999996
*/

```
function hungryDog(age,weight){
if (age >= 1){
  if (weight <= 5){
    let foodAmount = weight * .05;
  }
  else if (weight <= 10){
    let foodAmount = weight * .04;
  }
  else if (weight <= 15) {
    let foodAmount = weight * .03;
  }
  else if (weight > 15) {
    let foodAmount = weight * .02;
  }
 }
 else if (age < 1) {
  if (age <= .33) {
    let foodAmount = weight * .10;
  }
  else if (age <=.5833) {
    let foodAmount = weight * .05;
  }
  else if (age < 1) {
    let foodAmount = weight * .04;
  }
}

return foodAmount;

}

console.log(hungryDog(1,15))
```

I have no idea what I am missing here. Please help! Error reads foodAmount is not defined.

Comment: Declare `foodAmount` **once** at the top of the function, and then just assign to it in each `if` clause (without an additional `let`).

Answer (score 1):

Your need to declare your foodAmount at the top so that you can update its value in some if-else block and later return at the end. the way you have declared it, foodAmount would be available only in your if-else block but it's not defined when you try to return it at the end of your function

```js
function hungryDog(age,weight){
    let foodAmount;
    if (age >= 1){
      if (weight <= 5){
        foodAmount = weight * .05;
      }
      else if (weight <= 10){
        foodAmount = weight * .04;
      }
      else if (weight <= 15) {
        foodAmount = weight * .03;
      }
      else if (weight > 15) {
        foodAmount = weight * .02;
      }
     }
     else if (age < 1) {
      if (age <= .33) {
        foodAmount = weight * .10;
      }
      else if (age <=.5833) {
        foodAmount = weight * .05;
      }
      else if (age < 1) {
        foodAmount = weight * .04;
      }
    }

    return foodAmount;

}
```